# Instantiating an object to the position of another vector, hoping to change Y-axis in the code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I have enemies spawn by instantiating them and having them follow a straight path along the X-axis. When instantiated, I want some variability in their height to match the game background.

```
Instantiate(enemyPrefabs[5], waveConfigs[0].GetWayPoints()[0].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(.3f);
```

Here is my code, I am hoping to have the same transform position called, but to be able to edit the y axis of the `transform.position`.

Comment: Please post a valid and meaningful code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that your waveConfigs could have two float fields for minYOffset and maxYOffset.

```
Vector3 spawnerPosition = waveConfigs[0].GetWayPoints()[0].transform.position;

spawnerPosition.y += Random.Range(waveConfigs[0].minYOffset, waveConfigs[0].maxYOffset);

Instantiate(prefab, spawnerPosition, Quaternion.identity, null);
```